# How do the Predators select and transport their Trophies?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

In the Trophy rooms, we see that Predators have Trophies from their hunts. How do they transport all the human/alien trophies before being picked up from the hunt? Pockets? Or do they only select the trophy of the final prey?

When a Predator makes a trophy out of an enemy (Human/Alien) where do they put it, while on the hunt? Do they just leave the Trophies on the ground and only take the final or worthiest prey? I'm asking how/where do they carry the trophies, like pockets to hold and secure them? I'm mainly thinking of the 2010 video game *AVP 3*. What does the Predator Protagonist do with the Trophies you take?

Comment: Is that screenshot from *Predator 2*? Haven't seen the movie in ages.

Comment: @mario - I dunno. I just grabbed the picture off the AVP Wikia page on "trophies". I think it's from AvP2; http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Room

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The fundamental psychology of the Predators is still unknown to Humans. As such, we are not clear on their selection process for trophies. All of our information is based on anecdotal evidence.**

- It could very well be at the end of their hunts, they only take the BEST trophy or trophies, honoring the prey that proved most worthy while the others are discarded or destroyed. (As apex predators, they probably only want to honor the BEST with a place on their trophy wall.)
- With their advanced technology, it is possible they are able to prepare their kills for transport and once prepared the trophy will remain viable, stashed away in a hidey-hole for a day or two while they finish conducting their business.
- We have seen Predators with skulls on their belts, so it is possible they just carry them around until they finish hunting. The process they use for preparation must remove all trace of scent, lest it reveal them to other prey/hunters with strong olfactory senses.
- I imagine like Earth sportsman, they kill far more than they keep and would only mount on their walls the kills with the best stories; or in the case of the Predators the prey that almost killed them or nearly got away before being brought down by their superior hunting ability. I'm sure that's how they tell it.

[image: wall of trophies collected by Gaston in "Beauty and the Beast" (Disney animated version)]

Comment: Ah almost got myself an elk <=== ***THIS*** ===> big the other day!

Comment: "No one fights like Gaston, douses lights like Gaston... In a wrestling match nobody bites like Gaston!"

Comment: "I use Glovers in all of my deeeeecorating..... He's getting too old for this s**t, Gaston!"

Answer (score 1):

As we've seen in both *Predator*, and *Predator 2*, the Predator alien does collect trophies from at least as many kills as it can. We also know from *alien vs Predator*, *AvP2* and *Predators* (the newest sequel) that they have camouflaged ships.

It's not too much of a stretch to assume a Predator alien would store its trophies in a secure location, or in its own ship. With a secure location he could simply return to pick them up upon the completion of a successful hunt. Unfortunately for aliens, advanced technology can be easily thwarted by mud.